# Right Single Quotation Mark from JSON to Android

Tags: php, android, json, escaping

I'm trying to send some data from a database to my Android app. I created a JSON php page that get and format information from my database, and through json_encode(), I retrieve my data in my Android app.

However, I'm facing an issue here. Some text in my database has some right single quotation mark (RSQM). For regular quotes, everything works well. But for RSQM, when I display the php page, everything is fine, like this:

{"ID":"9039","Title":"La Bamba / **Twist’n** Shout","Artist":"Ritchie Valens / Isley Brothers","Difficulty":"4","Date":"9/21/2018"}

However, when I retrieve it with Json on my Android app, this is what I have:

{"ID":"9039","Title":"La Bamba / **Twist&#8217 ;n** Shout","Artist":"Ritchie Valens / Isley Brothers","Difficulty":"4","Date":"9/21/2018"}

(I had to add a space between the code and the semi-colon here otherwise it's interpreted and displayed as a single quote).

As you can see, in the php page the slashes are escapes, but not the RSQM.

I tried to escape it manually, with str_replace, but it seems the character is not found, because it doesn't replace anything.

I tried to handle it on the app side to by adding .disableHtmlEscaping() to my GsonBuilder, but nothing.

Here is the code:

```
val networkModule = module {

single {

    val customGson =
        GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(Lesson::class.java, LessonDeserializer())
            .disableHtmlEscaping()
            .create()

    Retrofit.Builder()
        .client(get())
        .addConverterFactory(
            GsonConverterFactory.create(customGson)
        )
        .baseUrl(BuildConfig.URL)
        .build()
}


factory {

    val httpLoggingInterceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
    httpLoggingInterceptor.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY
    OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(httpLoggingInterceptor).build()
}

factory {
    get<Retrofit>().create(LessonApi::class.java)
}

}
```

and LessonDeserializer:

```
class LessonDeserializer : JsonDeserializer<Lesson> {

private val simpleDateFormat: SimpleDateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("dd / MM / yy")

override fun deserialize(
    json: JsonElement?,
    typeOfT: Type?,
    context: JsonDeserializationContext?
): Lesson {
    val lesson = Gson().fromJson(json, Lesson::class.java)
    return lesson
}
```

I debugged it, and it seems in the 'json' variable in the deserializer, the text has already been escaped, so I'm not sure where and when does this happen, and how to avoid it.

Should I get the string as is, and unescape it in Java after ? Should I modify my php file to escape the RSQM first ?

Thanks.

**Edit:** Here is an example of single quote working well:
On the php webpage:

{"ID":"11850","Title":"Lemon Tree","Artist":"**Fool's** Garden","Difficulty":"4","Date":"4/2/2020"}

And on the Json string on the Android app:

{"ID":"11850","Title":"Lemon Tree","Artist":"**Fool's** Garden","Difficulty":"4","Date":"4/2/2020"}

**Edit 2**: Just to complete what this.mitch said, this is what I did, which is non deprecated:

I added to the build.gradle dependencies:

```
implementation 'androidx.core:core:1.3.0'
```

Then I imported:

```
import androidx.core.text.HtmlCompat
```

And:

```
lesson.title = HtmlCompat.fromHtml(lesson.title, HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY).toString()
```

Comment: You probably have some funky char in the string (unicode).  php's json_encode has a bunch of options for unescaping stuff, like `echo json_encode($some_var,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT + JSON_UNESCAPED_LINE_TERMINATORS + JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES + JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE`);

Comment: The funky char is the right single quote, but I don't know how to handle it. I tried different options for the json_encode, but it doesn't work. I think this should be handled on the app side, where the html entities code should be interpreted, and it is not right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using androids [Html library](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html). You can use `fromHtml()` to encode html escape chars.

Usage

```
import android.text.Html;

String yourString = Html.fromHtml(yourJsonString).toString();

// or use with a textview

yourTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(yourJsonString));
```

Comment: That's interesting, but it's not that simple unfortunately, because I need to store these info in a local database, to avoid retrieving them every time, and fromHtml is returning a Spanned type.

Comment: I feel like it's a bit of a dirty trick (as fromHtml is deprecated) but it seems to work, so thanks :)
I'd be interested to know if there is a better way to do it though :)

Comment: Could you just save it within the local database as is with the HTML escape chars; Then when displaying the text use Html.fromHtml()  within a textview?

Comment: Yes it is possible, but that mean you have to do it every time you want to display it, it's not very clean nor efficient.

Comment: Not a dirty trick very common and fromHtml is not deprecated they just update the inputs in API level 24. I would say your best bet is to use HTML.fromHtml when ever you're going to display text. It is quit fast and is really the only way to prevent users from seeing your HTML escape chars. :)

Comment: What I did is that for now I use fromHtml priori storing the string to the database, so then I can display it everywhere, without having to use fromHtml everytime. It works, so I guess it's fine :) Thanks